# sql developer-how spool with set sqlformat delimited instruction and have ANSI encoding output file

Tags: csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, ansi-c, spool

I execute this two scripts with sql developer:

1. with the code:

```
spool defaut.csv
set sqlformat
select 'à' from dual;
spool off
```

the file defaut.csv have ANSI encoding

2. with the code:

```
spool delimit.csv
set sqlformat delimited ";"
select 'à' from dual;
spool off
```

the file delimit.csv have UTF-8 (without BOM) encoding

I need the format 'field1;field2;...' with sqlformat delimited ";", but with ANSI encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 set encoding UTF-8
```

Then spool your file, it should have that encoding. That's working for me with your example query and sqlformat.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry, but I want encode to ANSI.
I tryed, under SQL Developer, the instructions "set encoding UTF-8", "set encoding ANSI", "set encoding XXX". The system display not an error, and the encoding spool file is always UTF-8.

Comment: Ah with ANSI, I read it backwards, my apologies